# How to pass arguments to a "Verbatim" environment from a variable?

Tags: fancyvrb

The arguments that I need to pass to a `Verbatim` environment are in a variable. I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\def\opts{numbers=left}
\begin{Verbatim}[\opts]
Hello, world!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, t fails:

```
! Package keyval Error: numbers=left undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.5 \begin{Verbatim}[\opts]
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generally don't want to pass a macro for options, but to define a new key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\define@key{FV}{opts}[]{%
  \setkeys{FV}{
    numbers=left,
    % additional options
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[opts]
Hello, world!
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

If you insist in passing macros, you need to expand them prior the environment parses them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\opts}{numbers=left}

\begin{document}

\expanded{\noexpand\begin{Verbatim}[\opts]}
Hello, world!
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

But I can't recommend this.

Another strategy is to define a new Verbatim:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{lVerbatim}{Verbatim}{numbers=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{lVerbatim}
Hello, world!
\end{lVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I define my options in a few steps, setting it once and then adding more elements to it, according to some configuration requirements. In the end I have a variable `\opts` where all keys are accumulated. Is it possible to do the same with the key you recommended? Can you please illustrate how exactly?

Comment: @yegor256 Some more details would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand `\opts` prior to the invocation of `Verbatim`.  Here is one way it can be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\def\opts{numbers=left}
\def\z{\begin{Verbatim}}
\expandafter\z\expandafter[\opts]
Hello, world!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]